# How to substitute an empty string (or null) with a default string concisely in Scala

Tags: string, scala

I have a method that returns a String.  I want to substitute it with a default value such as `"<empty>"` if it returns an empty string or `null`.  Let's assume its name is `getSomeString`, it is an expensive operation so I can call it only once, and I can't change its return type to `Option[String]`.  For now, I'm doing the following:

```
val myStr = {
  val s = getSomeString
  if (s == null || s.isEmpty) "<empty>" else s
}
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: If it wasn't for the isEmpty test, you could just go Option(getSomeString) to convert it to an Option[String]. Do you get both null and empty strings in practice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given an expensive function:

```
scala> def s(i: Int): String = i match { case 0=>null case 1=>"" case 2=>"hi" }
s: (i: Int)String
```

I think this is easy to read and free of overhead, cf [this in the wild](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.0-M4/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/util/package.scala#L75):

```
scala> def q(i: Int) = s(i) match { case ""|null => "<empty>" case x => x }
q: (i: Int)String

scala> q(0)
res3: String = <empty>

scala> q(1)
res4: String = <empty>

scala> q(2)
res5: String = hi
```

To my eyes, this is not as expressive, even with minimalist punctuation:

```
scala> Option(s(0)) filterNot (_.isEmpty) getOrElse "<empty>"
res6: String = <empty>
```

Moreover, contrast the cost in `anonfun` classes for the closures and additional method invocations:

```
scala> :javap -
  Size 1161 bytes
  MD5 checksum 765f5f67b0c574252b059c8adfab1cf0
  Compiled from "<console>"
[...]
         9: getstatic     #26                 // Field scala/Option$.MODULE$:Lscala/Option$;
        12: getstatic     #31                 // Field .MODULE$:L;
        15: iconst_0      
        16: invokevirtual #35                 // Method .s:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
        19: invokevirtual #39                 // Method scala/Option$.apply:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Option;
        22: new           #41                 // class $anonfun$1
        25: dup           
        26: invokespecial #42                 // Method $anonfun$1."<init>":()V
        29: invokevirtual #48                 // Method scala/Option.filterNot:(Lscala/Function1;)Lscala/Option;
        32: new           #50                 // class $anonfun$2
        35: dup           
        36: invokespecial #51                 // Method $anonfun$2."<init>":()V
        39: invokevirtual #55                 // Method scala/Option.getOrElse:(Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        42: checkcast     #57                 // class java/lang/String
        45: putfield      #17                 // Field res6:Ljava/lang/String;
```

The pattern match is generally just an if-else, smaller and faster (even considering that it doesn't optimise `s == ""` to `s.isEmpty`):

```
scala> :javap -r #q
  public java.lang.String q(int);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=5, args_size=2
         0: getstatic     #19                 // Field $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.MODULE$:L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$;
         3: iload_1       
         4: invokevirtual #22                 // Method $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$.s:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
         7: astore_3      
         8: ldc           #24                 // String 
        10: aload_3       
        11: invokevirtual #28                 // Method java/lang/Object.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
        14: ifeq          22
        17: iconst_1      
        18: istore_2      
        19: goto          33
        22: aload_3       
        23: ifnonnull     31
        26: iconst_1      
        27: istore_2      
        28: goto          33
        31: iconst_0      
        32: istore_2      
        33: iload_2       
        34: ifeq          44
        37: ldc           #30                 // String <empty>
        39: astore        4
        41: goto          47
        44: aload_3       
        45: astore        4
        47: aload         4
        49: areturn
```

But inspired by the other answer, even if I would never take this code home to meet my parents (because it incorrectly converts the value `"null"` if the expensive function returns it -- though maybe it's a feature to do that), here is a regex:

```
scala> def p(i: Int) = "" + s(i) replaceAll ("^null$|^$", "<empty>")
p: (i: Int)String
```

The `"" + s(i)` is a shorthand for `String.valueOf`, which of course produces the String `"null"` for a null reference value.  I appreciate SO's ability not only to generate quick answers to questions, but to encourage some out-of-the-box thinking.

Comment: The javap makes it hard to read your post and see your point. What is the tl;dr? That if else pattern match is faster?

Comment: @huynhjl Thx for the feedback. I edited so as not to bury the lead. (Newspaper term, not the metal.) Not that I expect to win hearts/minds on SO.

Comment: @huynhjl In fact, to put it more strongly, this is a no-brainer. But if the kids think it's fun to use Option, then there are worse things they could be doing like rioting in the streets and causing real mayhem.

Comment: Didn't know pattern matching can also match `null`. Thanks!

Comment: News editors intentionally misspell it, "bury the lede", I learned from webster's on twitter.

Answer (score 23):

```
val myStr = Option(getSomeString).filterNot(_.isEmpty).getOrElse("<empty>")
```

## Updated

I posted this code because I think the intent in this code is clear than if/else or pattern matching version, but I didn't consider the performance issue.

As the others in comments mentioned, this code is much slower than simple if / else or pattern matching(this line will create a lot new objects which is an expensive operation), so please do not use this code when performance is an issue.

Comment: Doesn't look *much* simpler compared with original code (and moreover,  this piece of code will be significantly slower than the former one).

Comment: I feel its lot cleaner.

Comment: It's not as clean and cheap as (ahem) my answer. Check out the carbon footprint.

Comment: @som-snytt You can be pretty obnoxious! Did no one consider a custom extractor?

Answer (score 2):

You could replace null with empty string in first step using `Option` and then substitute with default text if result is empty (whether because it was empty originally or because it was null):

```
Option(getSomeString).getOrElse("").replaceAll("^$","<empty>")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a method to `String` using an *implicit value class*

```
object ImplicitClassContainer {
  implicit class RichString(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
    def getOrDefault(defaultValue: String): String = {
      s match {
        case null | "" => defaultValue
        case x => x
      }
    }
  }
```

to be used like this

```
import ImplicitClassContainer._

println("hi".getOrDefault("<empty1>"))

println("".getOrDefault("<empty2>"))

val s: String = null
println(s.getOrDefault("<empty3>"))
```

so even the method call on `null` is handled gracefully (Scala 2.10.1).

Comment: @axaluss I do not understand your comment: The answer uses [implicit *value* classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html): It does `extend AnyVal`

Comment: i just wanted to add the doc link.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need changes:

```
Option(getSomeString).fold("<empty>")(s => s)
```

If you need to modify if for nonEmpty result. Simple example:

```
Option(getSomeString).fold("<empty>")(str => s"xxxxxxxx$str")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val myStr = getSomeString match { case ""|null => "<empty>" case s => s }
```